Why is water the densest at 277K?
From what I have seen/heard of, all the elements get denser and denser the cooler its temperature is; but for water, it isn't like that. After 277K, the water expands. Why is this? Is it because the molecules start repelling each other? If yes, then why doesn't it happen at higher temperatures? If not, then what is the reason?

A perusal of the thermal expansion coefficient vs temperature will tell you a different story. Various elements happily expand as the temperature is lowered. Look at the low temperature behavior of silicon for example (below liquid nitrogen).
